# Unexpected cast to textview; layout tag was relative layout

Tags: android, casting

I am new to Android programming, and I am having a really basic problem that I can't figure out. I am trying to make a Sudoku app using a series of Relative Layouts. But when I try to change the text in one of the TextViews in my app, I get this error:

> Unexpected cast to textview; layout tag was relative layout

Any help here would be much appreciated!

This is the java code that produces the error:

```
private void message (){
    TextView targetTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TL_Top_Left_Box);
    targetTextView.setText("1");
}
```

This is the underlying XML (quite abridged because the full code is very repetitive):

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.android.sudoku.MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/Sudoku_Grid"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="240dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Top_Left_Grid"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/Top_Center_Grid">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TL_Top_Center_Box"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/TL_Top_Left_Box"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TL_Top_Center_Box"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:background="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:textSize="17sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="0"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/Up_Button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/Sudoku_Grid"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:onClick="Click_1"
    android:text="Up"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you are selecting the id of relative layout instead of text view. assign id to textview and use that id in the message function

Comment: Exactly right, thanks so much! Answer was so obvious.

Answer (score 1):

This is where the id `TL_Top_Left_Box` is defined:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/TL_Top_Left_Box"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/TL_Top_Center_Box"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
```

You probably want to remove that id line and add it to the `TextView` contained by that `RelativeLayout` instead:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TL_Top_Left_Box"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're requesting the view with the id TL_Top_Left_Box and casting it to TextView.  In the layout, the view with that id is a RelativeLayout.  You can't cast a RelativeLayout to TextView.

If you were expecting to get a TextView, then be sure to request the correct id.  But if you were expecting a RelativeLayout, then create a variable with that type instead and cast it with that type.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks for catching my mistake, so obvious!

Answer (score 0):

```
<**RelativeLayout**
            android:id="@+id/TL_Top_Center_Box"
            android:layout_width="25dp"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
```

RelativeLayout is not **TextView**